# How to select a div with specific id inside table tr?

Tags: jquery

I need to show hidden `tr` which was `div` with `id="thumbnail3"`. How to do it using jQuery?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="table" id="table_of_books">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div id="thumbnail3" class="">  ...</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div id="thumbnail4" class="">  ...</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update:

I am trying to handle pagination. I am getting data using async json request. I am trying to hide all received entries in table. When *Previous/Next* button pressed I am trying to show one more entry. The only static is `table` and `tbody` (`tr` and `td` generated asynchronously by `js`). I am thinking of hiding `tbody` at the beginning.  And then show `tbody` and only one element which is relevant to current page. Is there more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Which <tr> are you trying to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#thumbnail3').closest('tr').show();
```

as you asked *I need to show hidden tr*.

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution is to use

```
$('#thumbnail3')
```

If you want to select it only if this element is in the table, you might do

```
$('table #thumbnail3')
```

but don't forget that you can't give a specific id to more than one element in HTML. If you're not specifically checking the element is in the table, you shouldn't use the latter, which is slower.

To show the `tr`, use

```
$('#thumbnail3').closest('tr').show();
```

Comment: If he's looking for something with an id, specifying `table` in the selector is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @BenjaminRH Did your read the text around the code in my answer ? The table is necessary if the div might be outside the table and you don't want to select it in that case.

Comment: The question is 'How to select a div with specific id .....' so i don't think this is a bad answer

Comment: Noted and downvote removed. But if you want to note to yourself that you're selecting something in a table, I'd use the context or leave a comment rather than adding unneeded conditions to the selector...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `id` is static, you could do the following,

```
$("#thumbnail3").parents("tr").show()
```

The `.parents()` get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. Read more about [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Answer (score 1):

To select the div, use:

```
$("#thumbnail3")
```

[jQuery id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

If you are trying to show the closest `<tr>` to your `<div>`, use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$("#thumbnail3").closest('tr').show();
```